# Как собрать определенным компилятором?

Tags: c++, docker, gcc, makefile

Использую для сборки образа докера следующий код. Скрипт выполняет установку protobuf + grpc. Сборку делаю на основе ubuntu:latest. К сожалению там по умолчанию gcc-9. Эта версия компилятора не может собрать протобуф. Там ручками нужно править фаил .h. Я устанавливаю в образ gcc-10. Но как я могу передать make путь до нового компилятора? Может кто сможет поправить скрипт, чтобы сборка шла с gcc-10/g++10?

```
   RUN git clone -b ${GRPC_RELEASE_TAG} https://github.com/grpc/grpc /var/local/git/grpc && \
            cd /var/local/git/grpc && \
        git submodule update --init && \
        echo "--- installing protobuf ---" && \
        cd third_party/protobuf && \
        ./autogen.sh && ./configure --enable-shared && \
        make -j$(nproc) && make -j$(nproc) check && make install && make clean && ldconfig && \
        echo "--- installing grpc ---" && \
        cd /var/local/git/grpc && \
        make -j$(nproc) && make install && make clean && ldconfig
```

Comment: `make install` там явно лишний

Comment: скрипт с оф образа по grpc

Comment: По идее, нужно сделать `export CC=gcc-10` и `export CXX=g++-10` (до `./configure`).

Comment: если вы брали в качестве примера https://hub.docker.com/r/grpc/cxx, то он является устаревшим, но довольно легко можно собрать по инструкции из репозхитория https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md